# what limit is being verified and what is its value?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $ \epsilon > 0 $, find an interval $ \textbf{I} = (5,5 + \delta ), \delta > 0 $, such that if $x$ lies in $ \textbf{I} $ then $ \sqrt{x-5} < \epsilon $

can you help me?

I thought if $ \textbf{I} = (5,5 + \delta )$ and $x$ lies in $ \textbf{I} $  we can say that $x  \in (5,5 ; 5,5 + \delta ) $

after that if the limit exists for every number $ \epsilon >0 $ there is $ \delta >0$ such that

$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta $  then $ |f(x) - L | < \epsilon $

after that I thought  $ a = 5,5 $   because $ x \in ( 5,5 - \delta ; 5,5 + \delta $ )

so $ 0 < |x-5,5| < \delta $

and now I don't know what to do how to find the limit  $ f(x) - L = \sqrt{x-5} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Note that if $x\in(5,5+\delta)$ then $\sqrt{x-5}\in(0,\sqrt{\delta})$. So
$$
|\sqrt{x-5}|<\sqrt{\delta},\quad\forall x\in I 
$$
Hence choosing $\delta=\epsilon^2$ will suffice and so $I=(5, 5+\varepsilon^2)$

Answer (score 1):

What you want to show is actually that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x-5}$ is right continuous at $x=5$. (Notice that $\sqrt{x-5}=|f(x)-f(5)|$. )

Let us **assume** that you have found such $\delta>0$. Then you have

$$
x-5<\epsilon^2
$$
for all $5<x<5+\delta$, i.e., $0<x-5<\delta$.

How can this be possible? Well, take $\delta=\epsilon^2$.

This is *how* you do an estimate in calculus.